# I re-installed node_modules in Nuxt.js and suddenly Must use import to load ES Module:~ appeared

Tags: node.js, vue.js, npm, webpack, nuxt.js

When I re-installed node_modules, I was suddenly told that ufo and node-fetch were missing. After adding them, I ran `npm run dev` and opened localhost in a browser and encountered this error.

This error also occurred when I cloned this project on another laptop, and I am at a loss as to how to fix it.

I tried to solve the problem by myself as much as possible, but I couldn't find a solution because the stackframe was somehow `Missing stack frames` and this error itself is an error in the library. I'm not very familiar with tack overflow questions, so please let me know if you find any problems.

error

```
Must use import to load ES Module: C:\Users\Cou\Documents\就職関係\job_portfolio\nuxt_main\node_modules\.pnpm\node-fetch@3.2.6\node_modules\node-fetch\src\index.js require() of ES modules is not supported. require() of C:\Users\Cou\Documents\就職関係\job_portfolio\nuxt_main\node_modules\.pnpm\node-fetch@3.2.6\node_modules\node-fetch\src\index.js from C:\Users\Cou\Documents\就職関係\job_portfolio\nuxt_main\node_modules\.pnpm\vue-server-renderer@2.6.14\node_modules\vue-server-renderer\build.dev.js is an ES module file as it is a .js file whose nearest parent package.json contains "type": "module" which defines all .js files in that package scope as ES modules. Instead rename index.js to end in .cjs, change the requiring code to use import(), or remove "type": "module" from C:\Users\Cou\Documents\就職関係\job_portfolio\nuxt_main\node_modules\.pnpm\node-fetch@3.2.6\node_modules\node-fetch\package.json.
```

Stack frames

```
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1089:13
Module._extensions..js
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:937:32
Module.load
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:12
Module._load
internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:961:19
Module.require
internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:92:18
require
webpack:/external "node-fetch":1:
Object.node-fetch
webpack/bootstrap:25:
__webpack_require__
.nuxt/server.js:1:
Module../.nuxt/server.js
webpack/bootstrap:25:
__webpack_require__
```

package.json

```json
{
  "name": "nuxt_main",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "nuxt",
    "build": "nuxt build",
    "start": "nuxt start",
    "generate": "nuxt generate",
    "lint:js": "eslint --ext \".js,.vue\" --ignore-path .gitignore .",
    "lint:style": "stylelint \"**/*.{css,scss,sass,html,vue}\" --ignore-path .gitignore",
    "lint:prettier": "prettier --check .",
    "lint": "npm run lint:js && npm run lint:style && npm run lint:prettier",
    "lintfix": "prettier --write --list-different . && npm run lint:js -- --fix && npm run lint:style -- --fix",
    "prepare": "husky install",
    "test": "jest"
  },
  "lint-staged": {
    "*.{js,vue}": "eslint --cache",
    "*.{css,scss,sass,html,vue}": "stylelint",
    "*.**": "prettier --check --ignore-unknown"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@mdi/js": "^6.7.96",
    "@nuxtjs/axios": "^5.13.6",
    "core-js": "^3.19.3",
    "csv-loader": "^3.0.3",
    "csv-parse": "^5.2.0",
    "fs": "0.0.1-security",
    "node-fetch": "^3.2.6",
    "nuxt": "^2.15.8",
    "pnpm": "^7.4.0",
    "ufo": "^0.8.4",
    "vue": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-server-renderer": "^2.6.14",
    "vue-template-compiler": "^2.6.14",
    "vuetify": "^2.6.1",
    "webpack": "^4.46.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@babel/eslint-parser": "^7.16.3",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-config": "^8.0.0",
    "@nuxtjs/eslint-module": "^3.0.2",
    "@nuxtjs/stylelint-module": "^4.1.0",
    "@nuxtjs/vercel-builder": "^0.22.1",
    "@nuxtjs/vuetify": "^1.12.3",
    "@vue/test-utils": "^1.3.0",
    "babel-core": "7.0.0-bridge.0",
    "babel-jest": "^27.4.4",
    "eslint": "^8.4.1",
    "eslint-config-prettier": "^8.3.0",
    "eslint-plugin-nuxt": "^3.1.0",
    "eslint-plugin-vue": "^8.2.0",
    "husky": "^7.0.4",
    "jest": "^27.4.4",
    "lint-staged": "^12.1.2",
    "postcss-html": "^1.3.0",
    "prettier": "^2.5.1",
    "stylelint": "^14.1.0",
    "stylelint-config-prettier": "^9.0.3",
    "stylelint-config-recommended-vue": "^1.1.0",
    "stylelint-config-standard": "^24.0.0",
    "vue-jest": "^3.0.4"
  }
}
```

OS: Windows
Node: v14.17.4

Answer (score 0):

Apparently it was due to pnpm not being able to install all the required packages.
Running pnpm install followed by npm install (or yarn install) solved the problem.